# Connecting wpf and class library?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a project with a basic frontend made with Windows forms. I want to send frames from a camera in the wpf file to a library so i can do calculations with it and then pass the result back to the form to display it.

I tried the same thing you would do with a class library and console app where I've created both projects within a blank solution and referenced it. But when I try do the same with a class library and windows form application I get the error "The Type or name space could not be found" and the waring "project "classlibrary targets net6.0 it cannot be refrenced by a project that targets NETFramework, Version=v3.0"

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core is not compatible with .NET Framework.

You will wither need to migrate the .NET 6 class library to .NET Framework (or standard) or upgrade the .NET Framework 3 project to a compatible .NET Core version.

I'd recommend an upgrade to get the benefit of all of the platform improvements.

More info on upgrading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I shared a link with some information about how to do so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/. You can explore the options there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the class library version you are using is incompatible with Form or wpf projects. It may also be giving an error because of null values. Changing the version of form or wpf projects at this stage will cause different problems. So you need to update the version of Class Library. I also suggest you inject dependency so that values cannot be returned null.